# How to use floating point registers in MIPS

Tags: mips, pcspim

I am trying to make a simple program for adding two floating point numbers in MIPS using SPIM simulator.The code is shown below:

```
.data
prompt1: .asciiz "\nPlease Enter first no then hit <enter>:"
prompt2: .asciiz "\nPlease Enter second no then hit <enter>:"
result: .asciiz "\nSum is : "
.text
main:

li  $v0  , 4
la $a0, prompt1
syscall

li $v0, 5
syscall
move $f1,$v0

li  $v0  , 4
la $a0, prompt2
syscall

li $v0, 5
syscall
move $fp2 , $v0

add.d $fp4,$fp2,$fp0

li $v0,4
la $a0,result
syscall

li $v0 , 1 
move $a0 , $fp4
syscall

li $v0 , 10
syscall
```

When I load the program in the PCSPIM simulator, it gives me an error message. But when I am using general registers like `$s0`, `$s1`, `$s2`) instead of floating point registers to add two simple integers, it works perfectly.

How can I add two floating point numbers by using floating point registers?

Comment: What error ? Please specify.

Comment: An error occured while loading the file

Answer (score 1):

Floating point registers in MIPS reside in co-processor 1 because co-processor 1 is intended to be used for FPU.
So to move data to a floating point register you will have to use **mtc1** instruction instead of the move instruction. It means "move to co-processor 1".

You can refer this document online for instruction set manual:
**http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3410/2008fa/MIPS_Vol2.pdf**

EDIT: Also naming of floating point registers is $f0-$f31 and not $fp0-$fp31.

Comment: I tried your program on XSPIM with the said changes and there was no problem in loading. But program itself is not able to add the fractional part of the two input numbers. Maybe its just an input/output issue, will have to debug and check.

Answer (score 0):

The error "An error occured while loading the file" is not a runtime error, but an assembler error. In particular, your source will not assemble as it has multiple problems:

- You cannot do `move $f1,$v0`, you have to use the `mfc1` (move from coprocessor 1) and `mtc1` (move to coprocessor 1) instructions for moving data from/to floating point registers.
- Floating point registers aren't named `fpN`, but `f0` to `f31`. Should you want to use double precision, you have to convert after loading, with (for instance) `cvt.d.w  $f0, $f2`

If assembly were successful, `add.d $fp4,$fp2,$fp0` would be trying to add the floating point registers `f0` and `f2`, but you have loaded the supplied integers to `f1` and `f2`.